# Adding subview to UITableViewCell content view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I add a `subView` to a custom `UITableViewCell`  from the implementation file, i.e. `MyCustomCell.m` inside the `drawRect` method? Instead of adding it inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the view controller ...

I tried `[self.contentView addSubView: view1];` but it gives this warning: `UIView may not respond to -addSubView:`

EDIT:

The code that caused the crash is :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialization code (add your view here.)
        [self.contentView addSubView: self.view1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: question updated with the given warning.. actually it was warning not error, im sorry

Comment: Can you post the code that gave the crash?

Comment: you haven't even initialized the view1 with anything in this case.

Comment: it's initialized with a huge code but did not post it here

Comment: the problem with self.contentView it is not listed inside the little auto-complete list when you type self in XCode editor, this means that the current uitableviewcell can't see contentView property !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's your misspelling; not `addSubView:`, but `addSubview:`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're calling the wrong method. The method is not called `addSubView:` but `addSubview:`. You can look it up on the Apple doc page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this...

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

// Initialization code (add your view here.)


}

return self;

}
```

inside this you can add your subview..
EDIT:

I used this to make my custom cells and it works fine.... http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `self.view1` is not initialized yet. You should add it later on. What I would do is, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` method, after the cell gets initialized, call a method that sets up the cell, adding the needed view or any other element that you need.

Comment: it's already initialized, but there was a typo in my code, thanks bro